# Using UINavigationController methods in TableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem concerning the UINavigationController. What I do is, I set up one navigation controller that takes care of one view controller, lets name it A. Now what I do is I put an UIView on view controller A and on top of that view, a tableview. The tableViewcontroller and its delegates are defined in a seperate class. Now what I wanna do is push a new view controller using the "pushViewController"-Method when the user clicks on a table cell. Do I have to pass the reference to the navigation controller all the way up to my tableview controller? Or how am I supposed to get my navigation controller from the tabelviewcontroller class?

Comment: check whether self.navigationController returns any value in tableviewcontroller class, if yes, then its your desired navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your separate UITableViewclass say(yourTableView) where you have the UITableViewDelegates,declare a property `id delegate;`
From your viewController say A ,subject `yourTableView.delegate = self;`

and perhaps in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath of yourTableViewClass
for pushing on didSelect
 as always create instance of newController to be pushed(e.g newController)
 finally..

```
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

Here 'delegate' turns out to be viewController A which you have already assigned a UINavigationController.
Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [tutorial](http://codenugget.org/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a) that I was able to get working.

I also read the official SDK documentation on the topic:  [Combining Tab Bar and Navigation Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningToolbarandNavigationControllers/CombiningToolbarandNavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW1). Since I'm still learning, the [tutorial](http://codenugget.org/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a) helped me more than the docs.

else try this code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 

// Create instance of UINavigationController
UINavigationController *myNavigationController;
// Create initialized instance of UITabBarController
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
// Create initialized instance of NSMutableArray to hold our UINavigationControllers
NSMutableArray *tabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Create first UIViewController
UIViewController *myFirstViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[myFirstViewController setTitle:@"First"];
// Initialize the UINavigationController
myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myFirstViewController];
// Add UINavigationController to you tabs
[tabs addObject:myNavigationController];
// Release UIViewController and UINavigationController
[myFirstViewController release], [myNavigationController release];

// Create second UIViewController
UIViewController *mySecondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[mySecondViewController setTitle:@"Second"];
// Initialize the UINavigationController
myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mySecondViewController];
// Add UINavigationController to you tabs
[tabs addObject:myNavigationController];
// Release UIViewController and UINavigationController
[mySecondViewController release], [myNavigationController release];

// Add the tabs to the UITabBarController
[tabBarController setViewControllers:tabs];
// Add the view of the UITabBarController to the window
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```